# css not loading in webpy

Tags: python, pycharm, localhost, web.py

it doesn't matter what browser I use,HTML file does get loaded but I can't load css file, I'm using PyCharm.
You can see the structure of my files here, if you think I'm using a wrong path to my CSS file.
[image: img]

**Controller.py**

```
import web


urls = (
    '/', 'home'
)

render = web.template.render("Views/Templates/", base="MainLayout")
app = web.application(urls, globals())

# Classes/Routes


class home:
    def GET(self):
        return render.Home()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**MainLayout.html**

```
$def with (page)

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CodeWizard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/css/swag.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        $:page
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Home.html**

```
<h1>Hello CodeWizard</h1>
```

also the content of my host file in etc/host is this:

- 127.0.0.1    localhost
- 255.255.255.255  broadcasthost
- ::1             localhost
- 0.0.0.0 account.jetbrains.com
- 0.0.0.0 www.jetbrains.com
- 0.0.0.0 www-weighted.jetbrains.com

is that relevant?

Comment: did you try `href=/static/css/swag.css`? URL `/static/` if I recall correctly, is built in for web.py, and looks in the directory named `/static/`, relative to the running app (i.e., Controller.py).